# My random playing card picker keeps giving me the same incorrect output?

Tags: java, logic

I am supposed to write a program for my first java class that generates an array of 52 playing cards, picks 2 at random, and checks to see if they match. I wrote the code and it runs, but there has to be a logic error because it keeps giving me the same output which is **83,K and 83,K match**. Does anyone know how to fix this? First post and new to coding so sorry if formatting is weird. Here is the code I wrote, it is in 2 separate pages.

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      ArrayList <PlayingCard > deckOfCards = new ArrayList < PlayingCard > (52);

      String chrSuit = "SHDC";

      Random randGen = new Random();

      int randNum1 = randGen.nextInt(1) + 13;
      int randNum2 = randGen.nextInt(1) + 13;
      int i = 0;
      int x = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {

      for (x = 0;  x < 14; ++x) {

        PlayingCard singleCard = new PlayingCard(chrSuit.charAt(i), x);

        deckOfCards.add(singleCard);

      }
    }

    PlayingCard card1 = deckOfCards.get(randNum1);
    PlayingCard card2 = deckOfCards.get(randNum2);

    boolean blnCardsMatch = card1.isMatch(card2);

    if (blnCardsMatch == true) {

      System.out.print(card1.toString() + " and " + card2.toString() + " match");
    }  else {

      System.out.print(card1.toString() + " and " + card2.toString() + " don't match");
      
     
    }
  }
}
```

**PlayingCard.java**

```
class PlayingCard {

  private int suit;
  private int value;

  public PlayingCard() {

    suit = 0;
    value = 0;
  }
  
  public PlayingCard(char suit, int value) {

        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
      }

  public void setSuit(int suit) { // Mutator
    suit = 0;
  }

  public void setValue(int value) { // Mutator
    value = 0;
  }

  public int getSuit() { // Accessor
    return suit;
  }

  public int getValue() { // Accessor
    return value;
  }

  //**********************************************************************//

  public boolean isMatch(PlayingCard rcvCard) {

    if (this.suit == rcvCard.getSuit()) {
      return true;

    } else if (this.value == rcvCard.getValue()) {
      return true;

    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public String toString() {

    String str = "";

    if (this.value == 11) {
      str = "J";
    } else if (this.value == 12) {
      str = "Q";
    } else if (this.value == 13) {
      str = "K";
    } else if (this.value == 14) {
      str = "A";
    } else {
      str = Integer.toString(this.value);
    }

    return (this.suit + "," + str) ;
   // System.out.print(this.suit + ",");
   // System.out.print(str);

  }

}
```

Comment: [`randGen.nextInt(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) will always output 0. Not very random.

Comment: If you want to pick any card in the list, your random number should be from 0 to 51 (inclusive) for 52 cards, or from 0 to 55 (inclusive) for 56 cards.

Comment: By the way, Your nested loops will create a deck of 56 cards. Your `ArrayList` will increase its capacity to accommodate the extra cards.

Answer (score 2):

First, your call to `randGen.nextInt(1)` always returns `0`. The number you pass to that call is a non-inclusive upper bound. See the [Random#nextInt(int bound)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) specification. To fix that you could use `randGen.nextInt(14)` to get numbers between `0` and `13` inclusive.

Second, your getter `public int getSuit()` returns an `int` instead of a `char` which is why you see the value `83` which represents the letter `S`.